# redirect without htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a site that is on a darwin server.

i dont see any .htaccess.(i can see .htaccess file in a different site on the same server.)

yet it redirects /file to /file.php

how is this done?

Comment: have you tried adding a new .htaccess file?

Answer (score 4):

This could well be defined in the central `httpd.conf` file. `.htaccess` is only a local representation of Apache's central configuration.

Also, the `.htaccess` file could be in a folder above the web root.

Answer (score 3):

In the httpd.conf or vhosts file, for the options under the domain `MultiViews` is most likely there. This is what causes it and is called [Content Negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html).

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to confirm confirm it is Apache's MultiViews doing this by disabling it  with

```
Options -MultiViews
```

in a .htaccess file in the directory in question. MultiViews can also cause issues with rewrites...